# Is it possible to add a button n times to an html file with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

As the title says, can I use javascript to create a button on a html page for every item in a list of size n.

If it is, could anyone give me an example of how this may be done? Thank you.

Comment: Hi welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you know how to add a single button? If so, you will simply iterate through your list and do the same for every element.

Comment: The answer is, of course, “yes.” But, as we’re not a free coding service we do expect you to show your own attempts at solving the problem (see the “*[mcve]*” guidance). Please, take the [tour], and read the guidelines for “*[ask].*”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just using JS without any frameworks, you can append a button to a container, and run it multiple times. Use `document.createElement()` to make the button, and `element.appendChild()` to append it.

```js
const container = document.getElementById("my-container");
const amountOfButtons = 5;
for (let i = 1; i <= amountOfButtons; i++) {
  const button = document.createElement("button");
  button.textContent = "Button #" + i; // add text to the button
  container.appendChild(button); // append the button
}
```

```html
<div id="my-container">
  <!-- Buttons will go here -->
</div>
```

Edit: If you have a list rather than an "amount of buttons", you loop through each list item using a `for...of` loop or similar, like so:

```js
const container = document.getElementById("my-container");
const myList = [
  "list item 1",
  "list item 2",
  "thanks for coming to my ted talk",
  "goodbye"
];
for (const listItem of myList) {
  const button = document.createElement("button");
  button.textContent = listItem;
  container.appendChild(button); // append the button
}
```

```html
<div id="my-container">
  <!-- Buttons will go here -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a for loop for `i < list.length` and create a new button each iteration, appending as you would like.

```
var list = document.getElementsBy(...); // Choose a method for selecting your items

for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    // Probably set the innerHTML/textContent and maybe class
    element.append(button); // Append to the element of your choice
}
```